# How to use one iMacros script to another iMacros script?

Tags: imacros

Suppose I have 2 iMacros scripts script1.iim and script2.iim, is there anyway to use script2.iim to script1.iim?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably because *this question doesn't show any research effort* ... first search result on google returns [iimPlay()](http://wiki.imacros.net/iimPlay%28%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for macros played in 'iMacros' for Firefox:

```
URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=script2.iim
```

(FYI, the `iimPlay()` function relates to the Scripting Interfaces but not 'iim'-codes.)